# proguard-rules.pro is not used

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

This is my `proguard-rules.pro` file: (I'm not sure do I really need to include rules for `com.github.chrisbanes`)

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.github.chrisbanes.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.github.chrisbanes.**
```

because I used:

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
```

I used that `proguard-rules.pro` file (without `com.github.chrisbanes` library) before for other apps that had google ads and picasso library and it worked.

Now I'm getting bunch of errors when I try to generate signed APK, like:

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzapm { void requestInterstitialAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzapm { void requestInterstitialAd(android.content.Context,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener,android.os.Bundle,com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest,android.os.Bundle); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter { android.graphics.Bitmap decodeStream(okio.Source,com.squareup.picasso.Request); }', but not the descriptor class 'okio.Source'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.squareup.picasso.Downloader { okhttp3.Response load(okhttp3.Request); }', but not the descriptor class 'okhttp3.Request'
```

It seems like Android Studio is not using my `proguard-rules.pro` file at all.

Also, what is new in this app compared to apps before is that in this app I'm using androidx and targeting API 28 for the first time.

Do you know where is the problem and how to fix it?

Also, could I just use `-ignorewarnings` and generate signed APK? Will my app still work normally?

Answer (score 0):

Check location of your proguard-rules.pro. It should be in app module directory.

I had same problem some time ago. My proguard-rules.pro was located in root directory of project and i moved it to app directory.

Comment: Just checked it and it's inside app module directory.

Answer (score 0):

> could I just use -ignorewarnings and generate signed APK? Will my app still work normally?

Usually, you should not simply ignore the proguard warnings without knowing its impact, but sometimes the warnings can be ignored as those classes may not be referenced by your app, so you can try to add below configuration and check if your app can work normally.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Also, your error logs actually are from proguard. Try different gms versions to see if it works. e.g. try `15.0.0`.

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```